# After upgrade to Rails 6: Content-Disposition header now adds strange filename*=UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-disposition

I just upgraded from Rails 5 to 6. When sending some file to download to the client, I now have a different `Content-Disposition`:

Before:

```
attachment; filename="Report_test_name Product_test_name A4A WCAG20 Project_test_name Project_test_customer 15-2015 v0.5.md"
```

Now:

```
attachment; filename="Report_test_name Product_test_name A4A WCAG20 Project_test_name Project_test_customer 15-2015 v0.5.md"; filename*=UTF-8''Report_test_name%20Product_test_name%20A4A%20WCAG20%20Project_test_name%20Project_test_customer%2015-2015%20v0.5.md
```

So it adds this funny `filename*=UTF-8''Report_test_name...` thing to the string.

I think that's just a new feature that I didn't know of. But what exactly does it? And why?

Comment: How about looking at the RFC that defines Content-Disposition in HTTP?

Comment: I found some explanation here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266: "Use UTF-8 as the encoding of the "filename*" parameter, when present..."

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-6, and that links to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5987#section-3.2

Answer (score 0):

This was a change added in Rails 6 that correctly encodes the Content-Disposition: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33829